# Select columns in different variables Laravel Excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I use Laravel Excel and I want to load columns separately, like this:

```
$rows = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($fileName);
$a = $rows->select($column1)->get();
$b = $rows->select($column2)->get();
```

Where $column1 and column2 are array with the names of columns I want to get.

In my $a i have the column1 but in my $b I have the column1 AND the column2. How to just have the column2 in $b without realoding the Excel file?

**EDIT :** The solution is to replace:

```
$a = $rows->select($column1)->get();
```

by :

```
$a = $rows->get($column1);
```

Comment: From where $column1 and $column2 are coming, I think, you wrote incomplete snippet here.

Comment: It's an example here, supposing they are the names of columns I want

Comment: Is this one http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export you are using ?

Comment: Yes but here is import : http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import

Comment: $a = $reader->select(array('col1'))->get();
$b = $reader->select(array('col2'))->get(); 
have you tried like this ??

Comment: Yes I tried but I have the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this:

```
$rows = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($fileName);
$a = $rows->get(array('firstname'));
$b = $rows->get(array('lastname'));
```

**Note:** `firstname` and `lastname` field is your column name

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly, I thought the result would be the same with get but it's not, the documentation is not very clear on that...